# Reverse tunnel issue

Tags: reverse, tunnel

I am setting up a reverse tunnel from localhost (win7) to remoteServer (Debian). On localhost I run:

> plink.exe -R 12345:localhost:22 username@remoteServer.com.

But when I try to connect back from RemoteServer to localhost I an error:

```
root@remoteServer:~# ssh -v -p 12345 127.0.0.1
OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 127.0.0.1 [127.0.0.1] port 12345.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
root@remoteServer:~#
```

I have enabled *GatewayPorts yes* in sshd_config and restarted sshd.
I run cmd.exe with Admin rights.

Answer (score 0):

solved. Needed to install SSH server on localhost (win7). plink.exe is just a client.